# Which browsers support Microsoft JScript?

Tags: javascript

Which browsers support Microsoft JScript?

Comment: Does "Jscript" have *any* advantage over real JavaScript?

Comment: IE and see different version support for IEs here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript#Versions

Comment: Why on earth would this possibly make any difference to you?

Comment: The only reason I am looking for such a thing is to add jscript support on our new webdevelopment paradigm called "Biz".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only IE (and IE-based browsers like Maxthon) and, if you consider the windows desktop sidebar a browser, the windows desktop sidebar which uses IE internally. So don't use it unless the latter is your target environment.

Other browsers support JavaScript though which is what's used for active content on websites nowadays.

Comment: JScript and per-browser JavaScript implementations are all implementations of ECMAScript, none perfect :-)

Comment: `JScript` has some horrible mis-features though. Creating a global var named like the ID of a DOM element for example.

Comment: Well, I know what you mean, but is that JScript or is that the DOM runtime?  I guess it's splitting hairs :-)

Answer (score 3):

*JScript* is the name that Microsoft has chosen for its implementation of [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), [Document Object Model](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) and related APIs. Microsoft does not call it JavaScript, because Oracle holds the copyright on that name. Everyone else calls it JavaScript.

Only Internet Explorer and browsers based on it's rendering engine support true JScript (i.e. including it's omissions from, deviations from and additions to the standards).